# How to evaluate an xmlhttpRequest

Tags: javascript, dom, xmlhttprequest, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make a tampermonkey script using firefox in which i use an xmlhttpRequest to retrieve external information, but I keep getting the same error in the console:
"Uncaught DOMException: Node cannot be used in a document other than the one in which it was created". I don't want to use the responseText to look for the information I need, I want to turn it into a DOM on which I can apply evaluate and refer to elements. But the way I'm doing it doesn't seem to work.
Anybody knows how I can handle this?

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "get",
        url: someurl,
        onload: function(responseDetails) {
            if(responseDetails.readyState == 4 && responseDetails.status == 200){
                    var parser = new DOMParser()
                    var to_DOM = parser.parseFromString(responseDetails.responseText, "text/html")
                    alert(to_DOM.evaluate("//tr[@bgcolor]/b[1]",document,null,XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null).snapshotItem(0).innerText)
            }
        }
})
```

Comment: Why are you referencing the document of the web page and not the document you just created?

Comment: Exactly, I just figured that out myself a minute ago lol. Works now. Thx though :)

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the document that is loaded in the browser, not the document of what you created.

```
const parser = new DOMParser()
const responseText = "<html><body><p><strong>Hello World</strong><p></body></html>";
const doc = parser.parseFromString(responseText, "text/html");
console.log(document.evaluate("//p/strong", doc, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).innerText)
```